# Print one line from file

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to read in a file that looks like this:

```
90 80 70 60
```

Here is my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    awk '{for(i=0; i<NF; i++) printf("%d\n",$i)}'
```

It is printing out 90 90 80 70. Why is it re-printing the 90 and not the 60? Also, isn't there a `sort -nr` or something that I can use to put it in numerical order once I get it to work?

Comment: If you just want to sort the input on a single line, try `perl -pale '$_ = join(" ", sort @F)'`

Answer (score 2):

Fields in `awk` are 1-based, and not 0-based.

You need to say:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d\n",$i)}'
```

---

It prints `90` twice because `$0` denotes the entire line, and the `printf` format takes the first field of the line and produces `90`.  Later for `i` equal to `1` to `3`, you get the other values, i.e. first three fields.

Replace `printf` by `print` and it'll be *apparent*:

```
$ echo "90 80 70 60" | awk '{for(i=0; i<NF; i++) print $i}'
90 80 70 60
90
80
70
```

Comment: @Tree55Topz `<= NF`. You need the `=`.

Comment: Awesome! any chance you know a way I could sort it least to greatest? something like sort -nr?

Comment: @Tree55Topz You could sort _least to greatest_ by piping to `sort -n`.  Saying `sort -nr` would sort it in the reverse order, i.e. bigger to smaller.

Comment: @devnull How does the syntax go for that? I did                       awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d ",$i)}' | sort -n               this syntax does not seem to work

Comment: @Tree55Topz Assuming that your file was 1 line as you stated, `awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf("%d ",$i)}' filename | sort -n`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `$0` is the *line* and `$1` through `$NF` are the fields. So you would need to start at `1` rather than `0` and you need to use `<= NF` rather than `<`:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf ("%d\n", $i) }' <inputFile
```

But, if your file has just *single* spaces between the items, there's a shorter way:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <inputFile
```

which will replace all spaces with newlines. Given the input file:

```
1 2 3 4
90 80 70 60
```

both of those generate:

```
1
2
3
4
90
80
70
60
```

And, yes, there *is* a numeric sort you can use, `sort -n`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <inputFile | sort -n
```

which will give you:

```
1
2
3
4
60
70
80
90
```

(and of course, `sort -nr` gives you the reverse order, `90` through `1`).

Note that piping through one of those `sort` commands will work whether you choose the `awk` *or* `tr` solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a single line, you can use `while` in  `awk`

```
echo "90 80 70 60" | awk '{while(i++<NF) print $i}'
90
80
70
60
```